# ¿como valido que una acción de determinado controlador exista en webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Como puedo hacer para que si el usuario intenta ingresar a un método en la API que no existe, este me arroje un mensaje personalizado y no el mensaje de excepción.

Donde debería controlar esa excepción?

Comment: pero si el usuario ingresa cualquier url puede que el request ni llegue a resolverse, es por eso que no veo como podrias personalizar el error, el mensaje que recibes seguramente es de http, sino existe seguro sera un 404

Answer (score 1):

Desde dónde y cómo estás consumiendo el API?

Te pregunto porque considero que en este caso quien esté llamando el API es quien debería de controlar este tipo de errores.

Por ejemplo, si estás llamando a tu API con un **XMLHttpRequest**, tendrías algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://tusitio/api/micontrol";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 404) {
        console.log("Recurso no encontrado").
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

En este caso, dentro del listener **onreadystatechange()** podrás saber cuando se produjo cualquier estado de la petición, por ejemplo: un estado 404 Not Found y ahí mostrarle al usuario amigablemente el error que se dió o redireccionarlo a otra página.

Comment: En este caso solo es el back-end, solo requiero que cuando se consuma la API (no se que cliente la vaya a consumir) si me solicita una petición a una acción que no existe, yo en el back-end le pueda decir al cliente que no existe, enviando código 404 ( que por cierto eso lo hace tras bambalinas) pero también generando un mensaje personalizado.

Comment: Como vos decis, esos mensajes los genera tras bambalinas, pero lo hace el **IIS**. No te funcionará si en la configuración del **IIS**, en la parte de **Error Pages** configures una página personalizada tuya cuando se produce el **error 404**?

Comment: No funcionaría por que es una API, yo le quiero retorna el valor 404 pero adicional mente quiero retornar en el respons un texto que diga, por ejemplo, "operación no valida"... actualmente le estoy devolviendo el error 404 al usuario y el mensaje de excepción. :(

Comment: Te entiendo, desde mi punto de vista si debería ser el front-end el que maneje esos mensajes, pero buscando un poco, talvez te puede servir esto: http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-handling-exceptions-and-404.html, aquí hablan sobre crear un Controller **ErrorController** para apoyarte en el manejo de las excepciones, hechale un vistazo. Talvez te sirva.